# Убрать дубли в view

Tags: drupal, drupal7

Мне нужно добавить GROUP BY в запрос который генерирует view. Для того чтобы убрать контент в которого некоторые поля одинаковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function NAME_MODULE_query_alter( &$query) {
      if(isset($query->alterMetaData)){
        if(isset($query->alterMetaData['view'])){
          if($query->alterMetaData['view']->name == "robots"){
            //Get a list of all 'group by' in the query
            $fields =& $query->getGroupBy();
            $fields = [];
            $query->groupBy("node.nid");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Не всегда нужно полностью очищать масив $query->getGroupBy(), это зависит по каких полях вы хотите сделать GROUP BY
По умолчанию у меня там были все поля,  поэтому просто добавить новое поле

```
$query->groupBy("node.nid");
```

без очистки массива не даст никакого результата. Так как GROUP BY по всех полях даст тот же результат что и без него.